# Can I hide new user's Donald medal?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-unchained-x

Before entering a quest I can see all my party's medals, but there a ton of new user Donald medals that get in the way when looking for a useful medal.

Is there a way to hide these low level medals or sort the medals by strength?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to sort or hide the medals.

Comment: Do you have a source or anything to back this up?